# Ansible ignoring nested host_vars

Tags: ansible

I have the following Ansible setup:

**playbook.yml**

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: true
  vars_files:
    - vars/all.yml
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="foo.bar = {{ foo.bar if foo.bar is defined else False }}"
    - debug: msg="foo_bar = {{ foo_bar if foo_bar is defined else False }}"
```

**vars/all.yml**

```
---
foo:
    greeting: "Hello, world!"
```

**hosts/production**

```
production ansible_ssh_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ansible_ssh_user=root
```

**host_vars/production**

```
---
foo:
    bar: baz
foo_bar: baz
```

---

When I run `ansible-playbook -i hosts/production playbook.yml` I get the following result:

```
TASK: [debug msg="foo.bar = {{ foo.bar if foo.bar is defined else False }}"] *** 
ok: [production] => {
    "msg": "foo.bar = False"
}

TASK: [debug msg="foo_bar = False"] ******************************* 
ok: [production] => {
    "msg": "foo_bar = baz"
}
```

Why does my nested host var `foo.bar` not work while the top-level host var `foo_bar` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour Ansible uses with hashes (dictionaries) is not merging them, but replacing lower-precedence hash variables with more specific ones. So host vars win over group vars, and extra variables declared with `vars:` win over both of those. [Full details here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

So in effect, when you add that "Hello world" in an included variable file, you're wiping out the `foo` dictionary in the host vars. You can see this by adding a debug to print the whole hash:

```
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="foo.bar = {{ foo.bar if foo.bar is defined else False }}"
    - debug: msg="foo_bar = {{ foo_bar if foo_bar is defined else False }}"
    - debug: var=foo
```

Which adds this helpful bit of output:

```
TASK: [debug var=foo] ********************************************************* 
ok: [vagrantbox] => {
    "var": {
        "foo": {
            "greeting": "Hello, world!"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
vagrantbox                 : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

If you need to combine the different values within `foo`, you can use the Jinja combine filter, or create a local ansible.cfg and set the hash_behaviour variable to merge.

I find merging hashes is totally necessary for managing lots of servers with Ansible, [Ansible official docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour) suggest not using it 'unless you think you have an absolute need for it'. Depends on your use case, I guess! But it gives you exactly the results your post would expect:

```
TASK: [debug msg="foo.bar = {{ foo.bar if foo.bar is defined else False }}"] *** 
ok: [vagrantbox] => {
    "msg": "foo.bar = baz"
}

TASK: [debug msg="foo_bar = False"] ******************************************* 
ok: [vagrantbox] => {
    "msg": "foo_bar = baz"
}

TASK: [debug var=foo] ********************************************************* 
ok: [vagrantbox] => {
    "var": {
        "foo": {
            "bar": "baz", 
            "greeting": "Hello, world!"
        }
    }
}
```